# VBA: How to interact with chart from VBA?

Tags: excel, charts

To interact with a chart from VBA, I need it's name. It's usually just called "Chart 1", "Chart 2", etc.

This is just silly. I wnat to name my charts whatever I want, and then access them like `.ChartObjects("MyChart")`, and so on.

Otherwise, how is a coder supposed to know what is being done when re-reading ones code?

How to accomplish this in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the charts in VBA you can name them in the code.

You could also refer to them by index, or create a reference when you create them.

If you are manually creating them you can change the default name given to them by selecting the chart and entering the name you want in the Name box.